# Why cant i use alias type for constructing? C++

Tags: c++, templates, using, variant, decltype

I have a Class called `SceneManager` with a method update that when the `exit` flag is `true` it switches the current scene to the `using next = nextScene`, but i don't know why it doesn't work, and the compiler isn't helping much.

I reproduced the problem in this compiler explorer space [Link to Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/55Pacao94)

My `SceneManager` looks like this

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept SceneType = (std::is_base_of_v<Scene, T> and !std::same_as<T, Scene>);

template <typename T, typename... U>
concept AnyOf = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);

template <SceneType... Scenes>
struct SceneManager {
    SceneManager() {}
    template <AnyOf<Scenes...> T>
    void change_scene() {
        m_current_scene = T();
    }
    void update_scene() {
        std::visit(
            [this](auto&& val) {
                if (val.exit) {
                    val.on_exit();
                    change_scene<decltype(val)::next>();
                    return;
                }
                val.on_update();
            },
            m_current_scene);
    }
    std::variant<Scenes...> m_current_scene;
};
```

My `FirstScene` is like this

```cpp
class FirstScene : public Scene {
   public:
    using next = SecondScene;
    void on_init();
    void on_update();
    void on_exit();
};
```

**Note that if i hardcode it like this it works**

```cpp
void update_scene() {
    std::visit(
        [this](auto&& val) {
            using next = SecondScene;
            if (val.exit) {
                val.on_exit();
                change_scene<next>();
                return;
            }
            val.on_update();
        },
        m_current_scene);
}
```

I've tried using:

- public accesors
- typedefs
- hardcoding it (this works but losses the generic sense)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to show us a proper [mre], and include the actual errors you get in your question. External sites can disappear, or get their contents modified, so please try to make your questions *self-contained*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val` is an lvalue reference, so `decltype(val)` is `FirstScene &`, not `FirstScene`. You also need to specify the dependant name `next` is a type.

> error: type 'decltype(val)' (aka 'FirstScene &') cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members

The full change is `decltype(val)` to `typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(val)>`

[Godbolt link](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/YebEKxroc)

Comment: `typename std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(val)>` can also be used I guess.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes, but `typename (const FirstScene)::next` is fine